# Какой надо вводить Package path в IDE Goland, чтоб можно было сразу в там же запускать код?

Tags: golang, ide

Пробовал по разному, но метод тыка в моем случае не сработал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по-разному это как-то конкретно?

Comment: Нужно объявить переменные среды GOROOT и GOPATH. И в дальнейшем писать свой код в $GOPATH/src/$projectpath. [Подробности](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Application run configuration — обёртка над обычным [go build](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies). Package path (или import path) в `go/cmd` это путь к пакету относительно ближайшего `GOPATH/src` или `GOROOT/src`.

Ваш проект не следует структуре [Go Workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) и `package path` у него не существует, потому конфигуарцию с `Run Kind=Package` использовать не получится.

В случае следования `Go Workspace`, IDE сама предложить значение Package path или предложит создать run configuration через правый клик по директории.

Решения два:

1. Следовать `Go Workspace`
2. Попробовать `Run kind=Directory`, где указать путь до директории